# Go Delve (1.0.0-rc2) freezes on Windows after breakpoint hit

Tags: go, delve

I have recently been having a problem which essentially makes debugging Go using delve next to impossible.  Basically I can't use breakpoints otherwise there is a good chance the debugged code freezes and all I can do is stop the debugger an restart.

To start at the beginning... I have had an intermittent problem debugging Go using GoLand IDE (2019.1) and delve (1.0.0-rc2) for some time. The whole session would freeze - I know that nothing is happening because the debugged process CPU usage is zero, and the fact that there are no messages being written to the log (I have many go-routines most of which are writing occasional log messages).  It's as if a breakpoint was hit but the debugger commands (STEP, etc) are not enabled which indicates that the debugger is *not* at a breakpoint. When this happens I have to hit the GoLand STOP button *twice* to get the debugger to terminate and then start all over again.

Recently this problem has become far more common. From perhaps a few times a day to almost every debug session. This is annoying but at least it has allowed me to track down what I believe is the underlying problem. It seems that sometimes when a breakpoint is encountered the debugger stops but delve or the IDE does not realise that - so there is no way to continue.

How do I know this? I proved this to myself by setting a breakpoint on a log line (ie, log.Printf). When the breakpoint is on that line (and I know it will be hit) then the debug session freezes. If I ensure there are no breakpoints that will be hit then the program runs absolutely fine including printing the log line. If I set the (one and only) breakpoint on the line *after* log line the log line is printed and the session freezes.

I think this is a problem with delve. Note that I have loaded the same project into VSCode and the exactly the same thing happens (GoLand and VSCode use the same version of delve), so I don't think GoLand is doing anything wrong. But if someone has another explanation I welcome it.

I have tried a lot of things to track down the cause.  I have created a small project in order to demonstrate the problem but it does not occur in a simple project. It appears that I am doing something wrong (in my large project) that causes delve to misbehave but I have no idea what that is.

Comment: I am still having the problem and have done a lot of research. There are hints of similar problems but nobody else seems to have encountered this huge problem with delve.

I suspect it is *Windows* related (and most are running debugger on Linux), so I have changed the title to reflect this.

Comment: I have reproduced this problem with a very simpler project now, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

First, 1.0.0-rc2 seems anvient forn Delve: the [current version is 1.2.0](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/releases)

1.0.0-rc2 is so ancient that a similar bug was reported in August 2018 ([issue 1318](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1318)) regarding an headless execution of delve:

```
dlv debug --headless ...
```

Adding `--log --log-output=rpc` can give you additional clues.

```
dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --api-version=2 --log --log-output=rpc ./test.go
```

> Delve itself, in headless mode, will ignore SIGINT.
>   To stop the headless instance you have to connect to it and then terminate the connection.
>   To send a SIGINT to the target program you have to start the target program, which you didn't, because to start the target program you have to connect to delve first.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I upgraded to 1.2.0 and nothing changed. Thanks for the info on delve command line - I'll see if I can use it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have given you the bounty. (I did not realise that it just disappeared if not used.) I was going to increase to it to 100 but now I know how it works I am _never_ going to use a bounty again.

Comment: @AJR No problem. Hopefully, this answer can help others.

Comment: I meant I should have given you the bounty as otherwise it was wasted and you provided a useful comment.  The problem still occurs with GoLand, VSCode and command line debugging but seems to happen less often with latest Delve.